# Assigning the answer of a function to a variable?(in python 2.4.4)

Tags: python

```
def BSformula(num1):
    """my formula"""
    (num1 - 2.0) * (2 / num1)

def main():
    number = input("value")
    answer = BSformula(number)
    print(answer)
main()
```

When I run it it always prints "None"

```
>>>
value: 6
None
>>>
```

How would I assign the answer to a variable?
or can I only print it in the def BSformula??

Comment: For the record: Python 2.4.4 was released [in October 2006](https://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/) and support for it had long ended when this question was asked - even 2.6 went end-of-life in 2013. In general, new releases of Python [are supported for about 5 years](https://endoflife.date/python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the keyword `return`.

```
def BSformula(num1):
    """my formula"""
    return (num1 - 2.0) * (2 / num1)
```